# Want to assert if certain Russian language text is present in a Rest response in SOAP UI

Tags: encoding, soapui, assertion

The text I want to assert is "являются".

However, the `Contains` assertion does not work for this text. Can anyone suggest a different way? for the Rest response in SOAP UI

Comment: Have you tried with custom http headers (adding a charset with cyrillic characters)? https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/teststep-reference/http-request/headers.html

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try with **script assertion** or a **groovy script** test step

Suppose your XML response is like and the test step name is Example

```
<Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Body>
<hello>являются</hello>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

Extract the value from the response XML

Let's suppose you have to assert являются

you need to replace testStepName and text in the below code

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("ZurichNB_1Driver1Vehicle#Response")
def data = holder.getNodeValue('//*[local-name()="hello"]')
assert data=="являются"
```

you could even use XMLParser to reach this node

```
 String xml=context.expand('${Example#Response}')
 def root = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
 def value=root.Body.hello.text()
 log.info value
 assert value=="являются"
```

Comment: I  am  looking in case of JSON  Response. How to  assert if the certain russian text  is present in  my JSON response. I  am able to assert it for English  Language Text but  not for Other Languages.

Comment: ok better you can edit your question and mention that you want it in JSON, however the logic should remain same only parser will change.. In the example taken i have taken the Russian word in the lastl line